# Dividing by the i-th element of a vector in Python

Tags: python, vector, division

I have a statistics homework assignment where I am asked to compute a vector of likelihoods. The i-th element of the likelihood vector is a function of the i-th observation of explanatory variables times a parameter. In the function, I also divide by the i-th observation of explanatory variables times a parameter.

When I write this function in matrix notation, the multiplication of explanatory variables with the parameter yields an (n,1) vector.

How can I tell Python to compute the i-th element of my likelihood vector by dividing by the i-th element of the explanatory variables times the parameter, instead of trying to divide by a whole vector?

I hope this question makes sense, I'm just getting into Python and am at my wits end.

I have tried two things that can't work: Since my vector of explanatory variables times the parameter is not square, I can't invert it to represent the division. I also can't simply divide by it, since it's not a scalar.

Here is the code from my two failed attempts with an example function (phi is a parameter and X @ beta is an (n,1) vector):

```
import numpy as np
import math

loglike = np.log(math.gamma((phi * np.exp(X @ beta)) / (np.ones([n,1]) + np.exp(X @ beta))))
```

And this is my attempt at inversing, obviously failed as well:

```
import numpy as np
import math

loglike = np.log(math.gamma((phi * np.exp(X @ beta)) * np.linalg.inv(np.ones([n,1]) + np.exp(X @ beta))))
```

Comment: You can use a `for` loop and divide the indexes individually?

Comment: You can also use the numpy `np.divide(matrix1, matrix2)`  to get a result where it divides the corresponding elements. See: https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-divide/